# Dot and word boundary at the end of the line

Tags: python, regex, word-boundary, end-of-line

I have this regular expression:

```
\ba\.?b\.?c\.?\b( something)?
```

that matches

- abc
- a.b.c.
- a.b.c. something
- ...

I use it 2 times in order of importance: first I try to add `^` at the begin and `$` at the end of the line because I'd like to find a string exactly those cases above. If nothing is found, the constraints are removed and I accepted strings like

- foo abc foo
- blah a.b.c. something blah

The problem is in the first case with `a.b.c.`, where the `\b` mess with the `$`.
So if I use

```
^\ba\.?b\.?c\.?\b( something)?$
```

the simple `a.b.c.` is not matched because the part in the round brackets is "ignored" and the `\b` near to the `$` has a behavior that I cannot understand. On the other hand `a.b.c` (without the last dot) will match

If I change the second `\b` with `\W` everything works but I'm not sure I will match other unwanted string. Any ideas of how I can resolve this with only one regular expression?

I'm using Python if this can be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem simply comes from the meaning of `\b` (see [source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)). This part `\.\b$` will never match anything, as there is no word boundary position to match (the position between a dot and the end of the string is not a word boundary position).
You should try:

```
^\ba\.?b\.?c\.?(?:\b|$)
```

instead.

With the "something" part, it'd give:

```
^\ba\.?b\.?c\.?(?:\b|$)( something)?$
```

(there's maybe some improvement to do here, but it should work)

Comment: Thanks but I cannot understand the `?:` part. Can you explain to me what is it? I thought about negative/positive lookahead/behind but doesn't seem one of these cases. Maybe a conditional expression?

Comment: That's just making the group non-capturing. A habit, no importance here.